# Why can't I remove Windows from my MacBook Air?

Tags: macos, bootcamp

I try to remove windows from my Mac. When I open Boot Camp Assistant and click continue, a notification appears.

[image: Bootcamp Assistant]

[image: Notification]

Comment: Are you able to translate these messages? They very likely explain the cause and what you need to do.

Comment: Setting the Mac into English language will help us help you. Also, do you use time machine? If you have a backup of the Mac, erase install doesn't take long at all if your partitions are such that Bootcamp assistant  won't touch them